# How to cut down on OpenGL UBO alignment padding?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I have a UBO (Uniform Buffer Object) that is shared between many drawcalls.

The drawcalls use a portion of a single large UBO using:
`glBindBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bindIndex, uboName, offset * alignment, alignment);`

- `offset` is unique to each drawcall (starting from 0)
- `alignment` is defined by `glGetIntegerv(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT, &alignment);` (some extra math is done if alignment is smaller than what I need)

My problem is that the alignment is rather large (256b) while my shader uses only a little bit of each alignment chunk per drawcall (64b at most).  This results in over 75% of the UBO being wasted as padding.  Worse, the UBO is streamed per frame, so over 75% of the data uploaded to the GPU is stride padding as well.

Is there a way or technique to work around the alignment and cut down on wasted memory/bandwidth?

Comment: Perhaps you could pack the data tighter (e.g., put four chunks of your data in each of your alignment-sized blocks), and specify an array of four appropriate storage blocks in your shaders, and then pass in an index into the draw call that specifies which block to pull data from.  The index would be valued between zero and three, basically being the draw call's count modulo four.

Comment: If you update the UBO as a whole, there is really little point in binding different ranges. Do you think your data wouldn't fit into a  single UBO, so you can simply use a tightly packed array of data, and just an index per draw call?

Comment: @derhass - I could do that, it's just troublesome to get that index into the shader.  I guess as a flat vertex attribute would be fine, but that's a lot of fiddly coordination between UBO, VBO, and shaders in my code, I might just put all the uniform data into vertex attributes to make things easy when it's too small for a UBO